# How to connect external battery to RPi?

Tags: battery, modules

I have a 3S battery controller module with batteries. It has output pins VCC and GND to which I need to connect Raspberry Pi. How to properly connect this module to Raspberry Pi to keep the USB port free? Is there any pins on board to which I can solder the battery module?

Also, I want turn on/off Raspberry Pi by thumbler. To which pins on board can I solder it? Should I just connect VCC wire through it?

Comment: You'll first have to have a circuit that converts the battery voltage to a stable and accurate 5v.

Comment: You should explain what a `3S battery controller module` is, or at least give its specifications (e.g. what is Vcc ?)   And what is a `thumbler`?

Comment: @NomadMaker I already have one. It has 5V and GND output pins. To which pins should I connect it?

Comment: @NomadMaker For i.e. this one https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32809351392.html

Comment: @Seamus https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32809351392.html

Comment: I couldn't fully understand the top of the page, but the device you pointed to seems to be a battery charger...

Comment: @NomadMaker It's don't matter. I asked to what pins should I connect +Vcc and -Vcc

Answer (score 1):

My preference is to connect the battery to a 5V [UBEC](https://rchobbytips.com/what-is-a-ubec/).

UBECs typically accept voltages in the range 6V to 26V and produce a stabilised 5V output.

Connect the UBEC output to the 5V and ground pins on the Pi's expansion header.  I tend to use pins 4 (5V) and 6 (ground).

See [expansion header pinout](https://pinout.xyz/).